# .dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, dll

I am integrating a web service in my web application.
The web service provided me a .dll and .jar file.
I placed .dd in /jre/bin and .jar in /jre/lib
After that I developed my code, and deployed the app.
During development, I also included the .jar file in my project build path.
On running it through tomcat, it gives me the error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library .dll already loaded in another classloader

Can someone tell me where am I goign wrong.
I did search this problem, but none of d answers were clear.

When I remove the .dll or .jar file, my program fails saying it could not find it.
I also tried removing it from my external lib, but that also din work

Please help

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load the same library twice.

Paste the class in a jar file under `/lib/`, it will be shared with other .WAR files.

Comment: Sorry,but I did not get you. Put which class where?

Comment: put the class that calls the native method in the /lib/ folder in a jar.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solve by removing other ".jar" file that was using one ".dll"

If there is same .jar file in your project and your tomcat/lib ( and may be in jre/bin) and all this ".jar" need to try to get one resource this problem occurs.

I removed all RxTxcomm.jar except one that was in tomcat/lib.

In my case i have "RxTxcomm.jar" in "myproject/lib", "tomcat/lib" and "jre/lib" and rxtxserial.dll was in jre/bin.

So my problem fixed.